# Add more than one space in a string

Tags: bash, whitespace

I would like to add more than one space to a string in a shell script, but apparently only one is added. Here is what I've tried:

```
$ abc="string"
$ abc=$abc"  at 2 spaces"
$ echo $abc
string at 2 spaces
```

How can I add those 2 spaces to my string so that they won't be trimmed?

Comment: You're adding them just fine. However, when you use a variable unquoted, it's string-split into multiple arguments. Echo then puts one space between each argument it's given.

Comment: I understand. I thought the spaces get trimmed when concatenating. Thank you!

Comment: FYI, if you're targeting bash, consider writing this as `abc+="  at 2 spaces"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to quote when echoing:

```
echo "$abc"
```

See another example:

```
$ abc="he           llo"
$ echo "$abc"
he           llo
$ echo $abc
he llo
```

Comment: Alright, I thought the spaces were trimmed when concatenating.